# Show only active windows in workspace

Tags: 20.04, workspaces, mutter

[image: Workspace Setting]

If I move Spotify or Gedit next workspace, it would still show me. I want to show those items only if I switch to the next workspace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with a hidden configuration setting. To have the dock only show windows of the current workspace, copy and paste following command in the terminal or in the run prompt you get when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-workspaces true
```

To revert to the default setting, issue the command

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-workspaces
```

Answer (score 0):

I WANT to see all the apps and windows from all my workspaces in the dock. I don't want to have to scroll through all 16 workspaces to find a specific app or window.

I tried the reset for isolate-workspaces, and I still see only the apps & windows for the current workspace.

Ubuntu 22.04